# How can I save all my outlook e-mails including message content, images, files, and recipient info?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

My school outlook account will soon be deleted. I would like to keep the memories I had while in school, so I'd like to save all the outlook e-mails I've received and sent including their message content, images, recipients, and more. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook includes an ability to archive mail (Exchange, IMAP and POP).

Go to Outlook, Options, Advanced, Auto Archive.

Set up Archive, give it a file name (that you can find), and then make sure all Outlook Folders are set to archive. Folder Properties. They should be set up.

Set the Archiver to run in a day or two and for everything 1 day old.

Everything in an email will be archived (email, to, from, attachments  and all that).

I assume your school account is Exchange and so Archiving is your best bet here.

Once the archive has been created, you can open it with Outlook of your own because archives are PST files.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, we can export email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file to back up. Please refer to this article to export:

[Export or backup email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.